# How to pass parameters to Perl module from Bash shell script, and retrieve values?

Tags: bash, function, perl, parameters, module

A function in Perl module takes 3 parameters. The value of the first parameter will determine the values of the other parameters and return them back to the caller. It is defined like this:

```
package MyModule;

sub MyFunction
{
   my $var_0 = $_[0];
   my $var_1;
   my $var_2;

   if ($var_0 =~ /WA/) {
      $var_1 = "Olympia";
      $var_2 = "Population is 53,000";  
   }
   elsif ($var_0 =~ /OR/) {
      $var_1 = "Salem";
      $var_2 = "Population is 172,000"; 
   }  
  
  $_[1] = $var_1;
  $_[2] = $var_2; 

 return 0; # no error
}
```

Calling this function from the bash shell script:

```
VAL=`perl -I. -MMyModule -e 'print MyModule::MyFunction("WA")'`
echo $VAL
```

Problem: The VAL only stores the value of the last variable or $var_2.

Question: How can I retrieve the value from both $var_1  and $var_2, for use later in this bash script? ( assuming code from perl function can not be modified). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Trying to return values by setting `@_` is... interesting.

Comment: You can do `return "$var_1 $var_2";`

Comment: The perl molule is protected. I cannot make any change to it. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Re "*The VAL only stores the value of the last variable or $var_2.*", That's not true. It's assigned `0`, because you print the return value, which is `0`

Answer (score 5):

Your function is modifying the value of its arguments **#2** **#3** so you may pass variables to it and print them:

```bash
perl -l -I. -MMyModule -e 'MyModule::MyFunction("WA",$a,$b); print $a; print $b;'
```

Comment: This suggestion works nicely. Besides, I can also store the returned values into array when adding space to the $a and $b. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You print the value returned by `MyFunction`, which is `0`. So that's why `0` is assigned to `$VAL`.

You should return the value instead of assigning them to the `$_[1]` and `$_[2]`.

```perl
package MyModule;

use v5.14;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw( import );

our @EXPORT = qw( MyFunction );

sub MyFunction {
   my $var_0 = shift;

   if ( $var_0 eq "WA" ) {
      return "Olympia", "Population is 53,000";
   }
   elsif ( $var_0 eq "OR" ) {
      return "Salem", "Population is 172,000";
   }
}
```

```bash
perl -I. -MMyModule -le'print for MyFunction( @ARGV )' WA
```

---

You probably want the two values in different shell vars. You could use the shell's `read` with the above, or you could use the following:

```perl
package MyModule;

use v5.14;
use warnings;

use Exporter           qw( import );
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

our @EXPORT = qw( MyWrappedFunction );

sub MyFunction {
   my $var_0 = shift;

   my ( $var_1, $var_2 );
   if ( $var_0 eq "WA" ) {
      ( $var_1, $var_2 ) = ( "Olympia", "Population is 53,000" );
   }
   elsif ( $var_0 eq "OR" ) {
      ( $var_1, $var_2 ) = ( "Salem", "Population is 172,000" ); 
   }

   return VAL1 => $var_1, VAL2 => $var_ 2;
}

sub MyWrappedFunction {
   my %d = MyFunction( @_ );
   say "$_=" . shell_quote( $d{$_} ) for keys( %d );
}
```

```bash
eval "$( perl -I. -MMyModule -e'MyWrappedFunction( @ARGV )' WA )"
```

(I'm assuming a `sh`-like shell is used.)